# In-depth Documentation of XML-RPC API

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

I was wondering if there is a single API documentation with "argument list" and the detailed description (and struct definition) of all the return values for all the blogging APIs like Blogger API,mt, metaweblog, and wp?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, WordPress doesn't have its own API, it simply supports others. The WordPress Codex has [a section](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) on its XML-RPC support. It says there that they support the [Blogger API](http://www.blogger.com/developers/api/), [metaWeblog API](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi) and the [Movable Type API](http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/movable_type_api/).